# Error during pg_basebackup

Tags: postgresql, backup

Im trying to create a cluster of postgresql-11 2 servers(cent7)
I added user "repluser" on main server in pg_hba.conf
on secondary server, stopped postgresql.service and using this as postgres user:
`pg_basebackup -D /database/db1 -P -R -X stream -c fast -h 192.168.1.1 -u repluser`
password promt
then error:
`pg_basebackup: could not create directory "/home/db1": Permission denied`
`pg_basebackup: removing contents of data directory "/database/db1/"`

/database/db1 folder is 777 permissions.
So why /home/db1/?
Help please

i was searching all over internet couldnt find anything, so im asking here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My goess is that you defined an extra tablespace at the location `/home/db1`. so now `pg_basebackup` wants to write to that directory on the backup server.

As [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgbasebackup.html) says:

> If the cluster contains additional tablespaces, the main data directory will be placed in the target directory, but all other tablespaces will be placed in the same absolute path as they have on the source server. (See `--tablespace-mapping` to change that.)

Map the tablespace somewhere else with the `--tablespace-mapping` option.

An alternative is to use the "tar" format with the option `-F t`.

Comment: it ended up source server have tablespace located at /home directory, thank you once again :) i made symlink to my directory from /home folder

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)